# Network Stopped Working (Ubuntu 14)

Tags: 14.04, networking

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 14.04. Wireless networking was fine this morning. Then it stopped working. Now, the Network Manager lists all Wireless networks as being out of range. I know they are not out of range. There must be a problem.

I see this message in dmesg, but I don't know if it is at all related to the networking problem:

```
[   18.767683] wlan0: Broadcom BCM4353 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.248 (r487574)
[   31.262020] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

I don't know why it stopped working.  I possibly changed something with the configuration (as root).  Applications were unresponsive for five minutes, I tried typing and clicking, but no response.  Then five minutes later, 10 windows popped up and I was asked to type the root password.  I might have inadvertently broke something.  Anyway, I rebooted, and tried everything I can think of.  How can I diagnose or fix this problem?

I also have a wireless USB dongle thing.  When I plug this in, it shows up in the dmesg output.  It seems to be configured, but then I get this error in the dmesg output:

```
[831879.866049] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan1: link is not ready
```

Comment: "10 windows popped up and I was asked to type the root password" is very vague. Check the obvious things first. Unplug your modem and router for a couple of minutes. Then plug the modem back in. Wait a minute or 2. Notice if the status lights look right. Then do  the same for the router.

Comment: I'm sorry for the vagueness.  The entire machine was unresponsive for five minutes, but I could at least move the mouse and try to click on the control panel, and the network tab.  When the machine started responding, all of those mouse-clicks seemed to take effect.  I don't remember exactly what happened, because I didn't know that would crater my networking.  Anyway, I'm at a semi-public location and other people are using the WiFi successfully.  I can't reboot the router.  How would I debug this from scratch?

Comment: "Applications were unresponsive for five minutes, I tried typing and clicking, but no response. Then five minutes later, 10 windows popped up and I was asked to type the root password."     Probably your keystrokes and clicks were being responded to, with a delay because some resource had grown critically short, and everything was being done sloooowly.  So, hard to know what menu entries or text entry fields caught those inputs. That's pr'ly why you had the windows and the password dialog. Xkill is real handy in that situation.

Comment: Sorry, figuring out what happened is beyond me.  I had a similar problem once,  albeit of diff't origin, where the only way to get the software I needed to restore internet access was the sneakernet. Pile trial and error on top of that & it looked like too much work. I reinstalled. Good luck.